# ¿Que es el MODELO DE DOMINIO en Diseño de Software?

Tags: patrones-de-diseño, ingenieria-del-software, arquitectura-de-software

Últimamente me he encontrado la palabra **MODELO DE DOMINIO** cuando investigo temas relacionados con desarrollo de software. El problema es que no lo logro entender este concepto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun Wikipedia:

> El modelo de dominio se crea con el fin de representar el vocabulario
>   y los conceptos clave del dominio del problema. El modelo de dominio
>   también identifica las relaciones entre todas las entidades
>   comprendidas en el ámbito del dominio del problema, y comúnmente
>   identifica sus atributos. Un modelo de dominio que encapsula los
>   métodos dentro de las entidades se asocia más bien con modelos
>   orientados a objetos. El modelo de dominio proporciona una visión
>   estructural del dominio que puede ser complementado con otros puntos
>   de vista dinámicos, como el modelo de casos de uso.

De esta definición podemos entender que el modelo de dominio son todas las clases, con sus atributos y métodos, como así las relaciones que surgen entre los mismos.

Por lo general del modelo de dominio surgen las clases con la cual programas las tablas de BD (que atributos y tipo de datos tienen las tablas) y cuales son las clases u objetos que vas a utilizar en tu sistema.

Por ej. 
Tengo que hacer un sistema de una cochera, entonces mi modelo de dominio estara constituido por las clases:
- auto: patente, fec_ing, hs_ing, fec_salida. hs_salida
- horario: fec_desde, fec_hasta, hs_desde, hs_hasta
- arancel: tiempo, precio
- encargado: id, nombre y apellido, id_turno
- turno: id_turno, turno

ademas en cada clase tengo los metodos get y set.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno esto depende mucho del contexto: Suponiendo un contexto Empresarial

**Dominio**
 - El dominio es lo que vas a resolver, de lo que se trata.
 -El dominio seria el negocio ( El problema que vas a resolver)
 - Reglas , Procesos, Sistemas, como opera la compañia
 Tal vez tengas que descomponer en subdominios 
 - Area contable, Area de Recursos Humanos, Proveedores, Mercadeo
 - Realizar pagos, compras..

**Modelo**
 - Es como vas a plantear la soluciòn
 - Seguramente sera mediante una abstracciòn de la realidad.
 -Es la especificación formal de una Función,Estructura,Comportamiento
 -  Dada por un contexto  y de un especifico punto de vista o punto de 
   referencia
 -Frecuentemente representado por una combinación de dibujo y texto

**Modelo de Dominio**

- Lograras organizar y estructurar el conocimiento del problema.
- Identificar todos los actores , componentes , sus relaciones y el alcance que se tendra.

Estos terminos los vas a ver mucho en :
**Diseño dirigido por el dominio**

- Poner el foco primario del proyecto en el núcleo y la lógica del dominio.
- Basar los diseños complejos en un modelo.
- Iniciar una creativa colaboración entre técnicos y expertos del dominio para interactuar lo más cercano posible a los conceptos fundamentales del problema.

**Arquitectura dirigida por el modelo**
 -El proceso de desarrollo de Software esta dirigido por el modelado de sistemas de software.

Para eso te recomiendo leer lo que escribe este genio [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Cuando tienes que analizar un problema para poder resolverlo te encuentras con dos dominios principales, el que atañe al problema en si mismo y el que atañe a la solución, por ejemplo un **array** que utilizas en tu programa es parte del **"dominio de la solución"** y no del **"dominio del problema"**. Cuando decides como te conectas también.
Cuando realizas el análisis tendrás que pensar cuales objetos son del **"dominio del problema"** y en función de esto elaboras el diseño del mismo.